# Multiplying in VB.net leads to 0?

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

I just got started in a VB.net course, it's not bad of a class but I'm struggling here. I'm supposed to make a "Mulch Calculator" I've done basically everything, besides one thing. I have to calculate the total cost based on the 3 boxes (Length * Width* Depth * 2.45D)

Current code is looking like:

```
Private Sub btnDisplayCost_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayCost.Click
    Dim strCalculatedCost2 As Decimal
    Dim strLength As Decimal
    Dim strWidth As Decimal
    Dim strAvgDepth As Decimal
    Dim CalculatedCost2 As Integer
    strCalculatedCost2 = Convert.ToInt32(strCalculatedCost2)
    strCalculatedCost2 = strAvgDepth * strWidth * strLength
    lblCalculatedCost2.Text = strCalculatedCost2.ToString("C")
    lblCalculatedCost2.Visible = True
```

The issue I'm having is even without the "2.45D", if I try and click Display Cost, it just shows up with $0.00 Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give your `strLength`, `strWidth` and `strAvgDepth` variables any values. Just doing `Dim strLength As Decimal` will result in it being set to the default value, which is zero. Thus, what is currently happening is that this:

```
strAvgDepth * strWidth * strLength
```

will always result in this:

```
0 * 0 * 0
```

If you're supposed to get the values from text boxes then you should use [**`Decimal.TryParse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify the input as decimals and to avoid exceptions.

```
Dim strLength As Decimal
Dim strWidth As Decimal
Dim strAvgDepth As Decimal

If Decimal.TryParse(TEXTBOXNAME.Text, strLength) AndAlso _
    Decimal.TryParse(TEXTBOXNAME.Text, strWidth) AndAlso _
     Decimal.TryParse(TEXTBOXNAME.Text, strAvgDepth) Then

    Dim strCalculatedCost2 As Decimal = strAvgDepth * strWidth * strLength
    lblCalculatedCost2.Text = strCalculatedCost2.ToString("C")
    lblCalculatedCost2.Visible = True

Else
    MessageBox.Show("Input must be numerical!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Replace every `TEXTBOXNAME` with each individual text box you want to get the respective value from.

Comment: @Unknown : Glad I could help you! Welcome to Stack Overflow, I wish you good luck with your project!